# To avoid text on the right of the icon to not go underneath the it

Tags: html, css

I'm having this problem below where the text next to it moves down to a new line underneath the icon when screen size gets smaller:

[image]

I was wondering what did I miss in my css/html?

```css
.event-details .event-info img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="medium -12 small-12 large-12 columns">
  <img src="http://static.igpandi.org/igpi_website/static/img/icon-location.png">
  <p>Cyberview Living Lab - Level 4, Cyberview Sdn Bhd, Block 3750, Persiaran APEC, Cyber 8, 63000, Cyberjaya, Selangor</p>
</div>
```

Comment: if you don't have any browser restrictions, try use flexbox

Comment: This is the expected behavior of `float`

Comment: If you don't have the `.event-details` or `.event-info` elements in your HTML then they shouldn't form a part of the selector upon which you're relying to style your `<img>` element; we need a code snippet that reproduces your problem, see: "*[mcve]*" guidelines.

Comment: I made a snippet for you. Please update it with correct CSS and HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `margin-left` of image `width` to `p` element.

```
p {
 margin-left: /*width of image + your padding for image etc*/
}
```

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
 }
 p{
  margin-left: 40px; /*width of image*/
 }
```

```html
<div class="medium-12 small-12 large-12 columns">
        <img src="http://static.igpandi.org/igpi_website/static/img/icon-location.png"> 
        <p>Cyberview Living Lab - Level 4, Cyberview Sdn Bhd, Block 3750, Persiaran APEC, Cyber 8, 63000, Cyberjaya, Selangor, Cyberview Living Lab - Level 4, Cyberview Sdn Bhd, Block 3750, Persiaran APEC, Cyber 8, 63000, Cyberjaya, Selangor</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case may be you should use `margin-left` for `<p>` instead of `margin-right` for `<img>` in small screen size

Answer (score -2):

Place both the img and the text into a table, then this should work.

```
<div class="medium -12 small-12 large-12 columns">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>    
                 <img src="assets/img/location-ico.png"> 
            </td>
            <td>    
                 <p>Cyberview Living Lab - Level 4, Cyberview Sdn Bhd, Block 
                    3750, Persiaran APEC, Cyber 8, 63000,Cyberjaya,Selangor</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```